# How do I serialize a C# anonymous type to a JSON string?

Tags: c#, json, anonymous-types, datacontractjsonserializer, json-serialization

I'm attempting to use the following code to serialize an anonymous type to JSON:

```
var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(thing.GetType());
var ms = new MemoryStream();
serializer.WriteObject(ms, thing);
var json = Encoding.Default.GetString(ms.ToArray());
```

However, I get the following exception when this is executed:

> Type
>   '<>f__AnonymousType1`3[System.Int32,System.Int32,System.Object[]]'
>   cannot be serialized. Consider marking
>   it with the DataContractAttribute
>   attribute, and marking all of its
>   members you want serialized with the
>   DataMemberAttribute attribute.  See
>   the Microsoft .NET Framework
>   documentation for other supported
>   types.

I can't apply attributes to an anonymous type (as far as I know).  Is there another way to do this serialization or am I missing something?

Answer (score 162, accepted):

Try the JavaScriptSerializer instead of the DataContractJsonSerializer

```
JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var output = serializer.Serialize(your_anon_object);
```

Comment: One hitch though. The JavaScriptSerializer has been deprecated.

Comment: Trackback, it seems it was de-deprecated in SP1.

Comment: for something so obsolute, it appears to be getting used in many new Microsoft frameworks, including MVC.  http://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/21528#266491

Comment: Works great for debugging in a test project with mock data.

Comment: How do I include this i a non-asp.net project (console application)?

Comment: @Alxandr: You would need to reference `System.Web.Extensions.dll` and add a `using System.Web.Script.Serialization;` statement.

Comment: @randomgui problem was project output type was set to client-profile.

Comment: Once this executes, output is of type string... How would one return this as an actual json object, say in an MVC4 application using something like "return Json(output);"

Answer (score 95):

As others have mentioned, [Newtonsoft JSON.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx) is a good option.  Here is a specific example for simple JSON serialization:

```
return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
    new
    {
       DataElement1,
       SomethingElse
    });
```

I have found it to be a very flexible, versatile library.

Answer (score 18):

You can try my ServiceStack [JsonSerializer](http://www.servicestack.net/mythz_blog/?p=344) it's the [fastest .NET JSON serializer](http://www.servicestack.net/benchmarks/NorthwindDatabaseRowsSerialization.100000-times.2010-08-17.html) at the moment. It supports serializing DataContract's, Any POCO Type, Interfaces, Late-bound objects including anonymous types, etc.

Basic Example

```
var customer = new Customer { Name="Joe Bloggs", Age=31 };
var json = customer.ToJson();
var fromJson = json.FromJson<Customer>();
```

Note: Only use Microsofts JavaScriptSerializer if performance is not important to you as I've had to leave it out of my benchmarks since its up to **40x-100x** slower than the other JSON serializers.

Comment: I am using the MS JavaScriptSerializer on the MVC3 stack to serialize objects with small amounts of data.  It's pretty fast in these cases, taking less than a millisecond to do what I need.  The DB query itself takes 50x-100x longer, so it's not really a significant bottleneck in my situation.

Comment: Premature optimization is a... Well you know.

Comment: "fastest .NET JSON serializer" link is 404ing! Plus, this answer is over 5 1/2 years old. Do you have an update on performance of various .NET JSON serializers?

Answer (score 16):

For those checking this around the year 2020:

Microsoft's System.Text.Json namespace is the new king in town. In terms of performance, it is the best as far as I can tell:

```
var model = new Model
{
    Name = "Test Name",
    Age = 5
};

string json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(model);
```

As some others have mentioned, NewtonSoft.Json is a very nice library as well.

Answer (score 12):

The fastest way I found was this:

```
var obj = new {Id = thing.Id, Name = thing.Name, Age = 30};
JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
string json = serializer.Serialize(obj);
```

Namespace: System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer

Comment: And for deserialization:         
             .                             .
    dynamic myObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(output);        
              .                      .
reference: Newtonsoft.json.dll

Answer (score 11):

*Please note this is from 2008. Today I would argue that the serializer should be built in and that you can probably use swagger + attributes to inform consumers about your endpoint and return data.*

---

Iwould argue that you **shouldn't be serializing an anonymous type**.  I know the temptation here; you want to quickly generate some throw-away types that are just going to be used in a loosely type environment aka Javascript in the browser.  Still, I would create an actual type and decorate it as Serializable.  Then you can strongly type your web methods.  While this doesn't matter one iota for Javascript, it does add some self-documentation to the method.  Any reasonably experienced programmer will be able to look at the function signature and say, "Oh, this is type Foo!  I know how that should look in JSON."

Having said that, you might try **[JSON.Net](http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx)** to do the serialization.  I have no idea if it will work

Comment: JSON.Net works just fine. I would argue that you shouldn't :), I think it's pretty legitimate in many cases.

Comment: After seeing the "throw away" types being used in MVC I can see some compelling uses.  I think it is a very handy tool to have in your .Net tool box.

Comment: This is a point I have also softened on, especially in the case of consumption-only types.  But if the object is making a return trip to the server, or is used in more than one location, I still believe that creating a type will result in fewer problems.

Comment: DataContract style de-serialization doesn't handle polymorphic types well. You have to write your own de-serializer. Too much code maintenance.

Comment: A use case where serializing anonymous types is useful is unit tests for web APIs.

Comment: Another use case, I'm trying to make a charting web service function where you just send it JSON data and a config structure in the same send, telling it what column is X and what column is Y... Since I know nothing about the data going in to the API, strong typing is foobar.

Answer (score 11):

You could use Newtonsoft.Json.

```
var warningJSON = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new {
               warningMessage = "You have been warned..."
            });
```

A faster alternative with Microsofts' new library on System.Text.Json

```
var warningJSON = JsonSerializer.Serialize(new {
               warningMessage = "You have been warned..."
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using this for a web service, you can just apply the following attribute to the class:

```
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
```

Then the following attribute to each method that should return Json:

```
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
```

And set the return type for the methods to be "object"

Comment: For a standard ASP web service [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)] is not needed on the method, [WebMethod] will do.
Also you should not set the return type to object, it can and should be strongly typed with a non-complex (i.e. can be serialized) type.

Answer (score -2):

```
public static class JsonSerializer
{
    public static string Serialize<T>(this T data)
    {
        try
        {
            DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
            var stream = new MemoryStream();
            serializer.WriteObject(stream, data);
            string jsonData = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(stream.ToArray(), 0, (int)stream.Length);
            stream.Close();
            return jsonData;
        }
        catch
        {
            return "";
        }
    }
    public static T Deserialize<T>(this string jsonData)
    {
        try
        {
            DataContractJsonSerializer slzr = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
            var stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonData));
            T data = (T)slzr.ReadObject(stream);
            stream.Close();
            return data;
        }
        catch
        {
            return default(T);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not serialize anonymous types as per the question