# How to serialize Anonymous-typed Objects to XML?

Tags: .net, xml, json, xml-serialization

Is there any possible way to serialize dynamically created object to an xml string?

```
var foobar = new { foo = "bar" };
string xml = ConvertToXMLString(foobar);
//xml should be something like : 
//<foo>bar</foo>
```

I was able to take a look at XMLSerializer and DataContractSerializer but XMLSerializer requires the object type while DataContractSerializer requires attribute on the properties that needs to be serialized.

Out of desperation, I converted the object to JSON first and from JSON converted it to XML.

```
var foobar = new { foo = "bar" };
JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
jsonString = js.Serialize(values);
//Json.NET at http://json.codeplex.com/
XmlDocument doc = (XmlDocument)JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(jsonString);
```

Comment: "`dynamic`" objects are different: `new {..}` results in a statically-typed expression.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I got mixed up with the terminologies.

Comment: Good call on the hack to convert to JSON, then XML =)

Answer (score 5):

Not using the standard inbuilt serializers, no; `XmlSerializer` **demands** public types (which anonymous types *aren't*), and only works for read-write members (which anonymous types *don't have*). `DataContractSerializer` wants attributes (which anonymous types *don't have*).

Frankly, the simplest and most supportable "fix" here is to formally declare a POCO DTO that matches what you are after, aka: don't use an anonymous type here. For example:

```
public class MyDto {
    public string foo {get;set;}
}
...
var foobar = new MyDto { foo = "bar" };
```

The alternative would be *essentially* writing your own xml serializer. That... does not sound like fun.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done using reflection, check the second and third answer in this thread for code examples: [Can I serialize Anonymous Types as xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2404685/can-i-serialize-anonymous-types-as-xml)

[MartinHN also blogged about this](http://martinnormark.com/serialize-c-dynamic-and-anonymous-types-to-xml)