# XmlSerializer to var object

Tags: c#, var, xmlserializer, anonymous-types

I am tring to use XmlSerializer with an anonymous type object

```
var obj = new { A=1, B="text" };
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType());
```

The Exception i am getting is:
***<>f__AnonymousType1`4[System.Int32,System.Int32,System.String,System.String] cannot be serialized because it does not have a parameterless constructor.***

Is there a way to pass this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to serialize Anonymous-typed Objects to XML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11896228/how-to-serialize-anonymous-typed-objects-to-xml)

Comment: You cannot serialize an anonymous type with SmlSerializer