# ASP.NET API action only returning JSON even when XML is requested

Tags: c#, asp.net

My API controller has two actions, one works properly and will return either JSON or XML depending on the request. The working method is basically the following and returns an `IQueryable`:

```
public IQueryable<UserDTO> GetUsers()
{
    var users = db.Users.Select(user => new UserDTO()
    {
        Name = user.Name,
        ...
    });
    return users;
}
```

Then I have a second method that returns an anonymous type that is a simplified version of the `User`. Since it returns an anonymous type I use a return type of `HttpResponseMessage` where I construct. The JSON-only method is the following:

```
public HttpResponseMessage GetSimplifiedUsers()
    {
        var users = db.Users.Select(user => new
        {
            Id = user.Id,
            OtherIds = user.Others.Select(o=>o.Id),
            ...
        });

        return this.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK,users);
    }
```

Why is this second method only returning JSON? I have played around with Fiddler and Chrome and adjusting the `Accept` request headers. If XML is requested there is an error `500` with the following error:

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?QzpcZ2l0XGJvb3RjYW1wXExhYnNcTE1TIExhYlxMZWFybmluZ01hbmFnZW1lbnRTeXN0ZW1cTGVhcm5pbmdNYW5hZ2VtZW50U3lzdGVtXGFwaVx1c2Vyc1xzaW1wbGU=?=
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Mon, 27 Jul 2015 17:06:26 GMT
Content-Length: 3894

<Error><Message>An error has occurred.</Message><ExceptionMessage>The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/xml; charset=utf-8'.</ExceptionMessage><ExceptionType>System.InvalidOperationException</ExceptionType><StackTrace /><InnerException><Message>An error has occurred.</Message><ExceptionMessage>Type '&lt;&gt;f__AnonymousType2`4[System.Int32,System.String,System.String,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Int32]]' cannot be serialized. Consider marking it with the DataContractAttribute attribute, and marking all of its members you want serialized with the DataMemberAttribute attribute.  If the type is a collection, consider marking it with the CollectionDataContractAttribute.  See the Microsoft .NET Framework documentation for other supported types.</ExceptionMessage><ExceptionType>System.Runtime.Serialization.InvalidDataContractException</ExceptionType><StackTrace>   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.DataContractCriticalHelper.ThrowInvalidDataContractException(String message, Type type)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.DataContractCriticalHelper.CreateDataContract(Int32 id, RuntimeTypeHandle typeHandle, Type type)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.DataContractCriticalHelper.GetDataContractSkipValidation(Int32 id, RuntimeTypeHandle typeHandle, Type type)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerContext.GetDataContract(Int32 id, RuntimeTypeHandle typeHandle)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.InternalSerialize(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, Boolean isDeclaredType, Boolean writeXsiType, Int32 declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)
   at WriteArrayOf_x003C__x003E_f__AnonymousType2OfintstringstringArrayOfintNHLuklIfToXml(XmlWriterDelegator , Object , XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext , CollectionDataContract )
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.CollectionDataContract.WriteXmlValue(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext context)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.WriteDataContractValue(DataContract dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.SerializeWithoutXsiType(DataContract dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.InternalWriteObjectContent(XmlWriterDelegator writer, Object graph, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.InternalWriteObject(XmlWriterDelegator writer, Object graph, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.WriteObjectHandleExceptions(XmlWriterDelegator writer, Object graph, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.WriteObject(XmlWriter writer, Object graph)
   at System.Net.Http.Formatting.XmlMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStream(Type type, Object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content)
   at System.Net.Http.Formatting.XmlMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStreamAsync(Type type, Object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content, TransportContext transportContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at System.Web.Http.WebHost.HttpControllerHandler.&lt;WriteBufferedResponseContentAsync&gt;d__1b.MoveNext()</StackTrace></InnerException></Error>
```

**EDIT: Clarified issue and added error response.**

Comment: What about the request? What `Accepts` is supplied?

Comment: I misspoke in my question I will fix that. The Accept header in Chrome is " text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8 " and in Fiddler I have tried just "application/xml " and both result in an error `500`

Comment: I just realized my question is missing an important amount of information which is the error from the error code 500. I have fixed the question to be more descriptive.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2404685/can-i-serialize-anonymous-types-as-xml) seems to indicate that there's no way to serialize anonymous types into XML out-of-the-box, and the answers seem to indicate that doing so is more trouble than it's worth. I'd probably stick with the "use a real class instead" comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the stack trace there is following information:

> Type'<>f__AnonymousType2`4[System.Int32,System.String,System.String,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Int32]]'
>   cannot be serialized. Consider marking it with the
>   DataContractAttribute attribute, and marking all of its members you
>   want serialized with the DataMemberAttribute attribute.  If the type
>   is a collection, consider marking it with the
>   CollectionDataContractAttribute.  See the Microsoft .NET Framework
>   documentation for other supported types.

So it looks like you cannot serialize collection of annonymous classes.

Try creating dedicated class for response or use `UserDTO` if it is applicable in your new method.