# cannot be serialized because it does not have a parameterless constructor

Tags: c#, wcf, salesforce, anonymous-types

I am calling a SalesForce API added as a WebReference in my Console Test application.

one of the parameter that it requires is of type object. To be precise, following is my code:

```
 SFObject sfObject = new SFObject
            {
                type = "User",
                Item = new { ExternalId = 2}
            };
```

I am passing the code above where API is expecting the Item's type to be **object().**

When I make the final call, I am seeing following error:

> {"<>f__AnonymousType0`1[System.Int32] cannot be serialized

Below is definition of SFObject as my **"Add web reference"** downloaded it.

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.6.81.0")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="urn:sfobject.sfapi.successfactors.com")]
    public partial class SFObject {

        private object itemField;

        private string typeField;

        private System.Xml.XmlElement[] anyField;

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("businessKeys", typeof(BusinessKeys))]
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("id", typeof(string))]
        public object Item {
            get {
                return this.itemField;
            }
            set {
                this.itemField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public string type {
            get {
                return this.typeField;
            }
            set {
                this.typeField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAnyElementAttribute()]
        public System.Xml.XmlElement[] Any {
            get {
                return this.anyField;
            }
            set {
                this.anyField = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

I searched around and seems like there is some problem with WCF serialization but I am not using WCf here. Is there any way that I can get around this problem?

Comment: Please metion SFObject class and this properties and all of things that relevance to it.

Comment: @vahidkargar: just added the info

Comment: What's not clear about the error? Anonymous types can't be serialized.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I serialize Anonymous Types as xml?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2404685/can-i-serialize-anonymous-types-as-xml)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the short answer for this lies in the folloing piece of the code:

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("businessKeys", typeof(BusinessKeys))]
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("id", typeof(string))]
        public object Item {
            get {
                return this.itemField;
            }
            set {
                this.itemField = value;
            }
        }
```

where

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("businessKeys", typeof(BusinessKeys))]
            [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("id", typeof(string))]
```

part of it demands it to be either of Type **String** or of Type **BusinessKeys**. If anything else is sent over then it will get rejected as unexpected type. If you try to fool the system with **new{}** keyword then it will throw the error that it just did throw.