# Serializing an list of anonymous objects to XML

Tags: .net, xml, anonymous-class

I am attempting to find .NET code to convert a list of anonymous objects to an XML string, but have failed so far.  The anonymous objects do not contain any sub lists, it's just a set of values.  The XmlSerializer class throws an exception if an anonymous type is passed to it.  Can anyone provide code to do this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2404685/can-i-serialize-anonymous-types-as-xml/2404984#2404984 Could this help you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing a function do do that was fairly simple:

```
public XElement ListToXML<T>(List<T> list)
{    
  var result = new XElement("Data");
  var props = typeof(T).GetProperties();
  foreach (var item in list)
  {
    var line = new XElement("Record");
    foreach (var prop in props)
    {
      var value = prop.GetValue(item);
      var element = new XElement(prop.Name, value);
      line.Add(element);
    }
    result.Add(line);
  }

  return result;
}
```