# Xml Parameter needed from LIst in C#

Tags: c#, xml, model-view-controller

Using LINQ to SQl I am storing a list to a variable. In my controller. I now need to pass this list stored in the variable to an XML parameter that can be called in another stored procedure. Can someone show me how to store the last XML? Thanks!

```
  var myVariableToAList = (from s in myResults.MyResultsList
                                select new MyResultsViewModel
                                {
                                    Id = s.Id,                                      
                                    Name = s.Name,
                                    PhoneNo1 = s.PhoneNo1,
                                    PhoneNo2 = s.PhoneNo2
                                }).ToList();


      myVariableToAList = ( I need to store this list as an XML Parameter)
```

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2404685

Comment: I don't understand. What is an "XML Parameter"? Parameters are not "called" in stored procedures. Is your question simply how to convert the list to XML?

Answer (score 1):

You could try to store that list as JSON into an XML parameter.

Comment: That will create an XElement, but surely not what the user wants. Have you tried this to see what it creates?

Comment: I changed my answer