# How to easily log a dictionary of arguments and serialize to JSON using Trace in C#

Tags: .net, logging, dynamic, dictionary

I need a flexible way to log keyvalue pairs of arguments using System.Diagnostics.Trace.

Basically, when I need to log something in code I would like to make a method call which passes a message and a dictionary of values. Its obviously not hard but I want to make it clean and if possible enforce the key names which are allowed. This is because I want be able to parse the keypair values out later and construct a log viewer which lets you search and sort by the arguments that have been logged.

One way I've experimented with was using the new .Net 4 optional method parameters.

```
public static void LogInformation(string message, int? someID = null, string someValue = null, int? anotherID = null, int? andAnotherID = null)
```

I could then call it this like:

```
Logger.LogInformation("themessage", someID:5, andAnotherID:2);
```

This method would then check every parameter and IF it had a value THEN it would add it to an internally built dictionary using consistent key names. I would then serialize the dictionary to JSON and pass it to the Trace.LogInformation method as the message. But this seems way too complicated to maintain. I would have to keep adding new lines in this method as our code-base grew and new values needed to be recorded.

I've also tried giving up the idea of locking down on key names and just trying to find a simple way to pass keypair values to a log method without having to do this:

```
LogInformation("themessage", new Dictionary<string,string>(){{"someID","1"},{"andAnotherID","2"}});
```

I tried going down the anonymous & dynamic type route so that developer could call the method like this:

```
LogInformation("themessage", new { someID = 1, andAnotherID = 2 });
```

But you can't use the standard serialization libraries to turn that anonymous or dynamic object into JSON.

Are there any other options or ideas I should investigate? Performance is obviously something I need to consider as well, since this method will be called from all over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually serialize an anonymous object to JSON using the JavaScriptSerializer

```
JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var output = serializer.Serialize(your_anon_object);
```

see this thread:

[How do I serialize a C# anonymous type to a JSON string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/331976/how-do-i-serialize-a-c-anonymous-type-to-a-json-string)

And if you want to enforce certain 'keys', is there any reason you don't just want to use a strongly typed class?

Comment: Because the list off possible values to log will keep growing and growing. Also, I didn't want to use JavaScriptSerializer because I thought it was deprecated. Looks like it isn't anymore.

Comment: OK. However, if you don't have to define the 'keys' runtime, you'll have to define them somewhere compile time, and I don't see the problem with a class with a lot of properties. (some people do though, matter of taste I guess :))