# How can I serialize an object in Javascript, then deserialize it in asp.net?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have a custom Javascript object that has a few string and float members. I'd like to serialize an array of them in Javascript, assign the result to a hidden field, and then retrieve and deserialize them in the codebehind for my asp.net application.

Is there a standard way to do this?

Comment: I clarified my question because it wasn't clear before that I want to serialize to JSON in javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what you need is `JSON`.

both javascript and C# can handle it.

article: http://www.nateirwin.net/2008/11/20/json-array-to-c-using-jsonnet/

also: http://www.json.org/ (scroll to the end)

Comment: So is there a native serializer in javascript to serialize to JSON? I want to avoid more plugins where possible, especially dlls for .net

Comment: JSON IS javascript. it stands for JavaScript Object Notation. In asp.net you might need a dll.

Comment: So how do I convert a javascript object to JSON, in javascript, so I can pop it into a hidden field and handle it on submit?

Comment: Updated link: [http://nateirwin.net/blog/json-array-to-c-using-jsonnet.html](http://nateirwin.net/blog/json-array-to-c-using-jsonnet.html)

Answer (score 3):

You can Use JSON.

With JSON you serialize data and serialize it in Different language.

http://flexjson.sourceforge.net/

http://forums.c-sharpcorner.com/Blogs/BlogDetail.aspx?BlogId=2028

http://www.nateirwin.net/2008/11/20/json-array-to-c-using-jsonnet/

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299886.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/79435/Deserialize-JSON-with-Csharp.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Check this answer [How do I serialize a C# anonymous type to a JSON string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/331976/how-do-i-serialize-a-c-anonymous-type-to-a-json-string)

**Edit:**
Since `JavaScriptSerializer` is deprecated .. you can use `DataContractJsonSerializer`.
MSDN: [DataContractJsonSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer.aspx)
Blog post on how to use it: http://pietschsoft.com/post/2008/02/NET-35-JSON-Serialization-using-the-DataContractJsonSerializer.aspx