# Serialize Unknown Types with DataContractJsonSerializer

Tags: c#, silverlight, serialization

i have this method to serialize my objects :

```
    private static byte[] GetBytes(object obj) {
        byte[] result;
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream()) {
            DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(obj.GetType());

            ser.WriteObject(ms, obj);
            result = ms.ToArray();
            ms.Close();
        }
        return result;
    }
```

it is normal, when i want to use this, my object parameter must a class that decorate with [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract] and its member must decorate with [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMember] but how about when i want to use unknown type like :

```
var myVar = GetBytes(new { Name = "MyName", LastName = "LastName" });
```

how can i decorate unknown types with attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DataContractJsonSerializer does not work with Anonymous Types. Consider simply sending a Dictionary over the wire if defining a specific Type with DataContract is not possible/justified.

Take a look at this thread also [How do I serialize a C# anonymous type to a JSON string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/331976/how-do-i-serialize-a-c-sharp-anonymous-type-to-a-json-string).

Comment: link that you sent me, some one say use JavaScriptSerializer and this class is in System.Web.Extensions.dll, but i cannot use it in Silverlight, other one say use Newtonsoft JSON.NET but also this cannot use in Silverlight, thanks

Comment: Quote : "Json.NET supports Windows, Silverlight, Windows Phone, Mono, MonoTouch and MonoDroid"

Comment: yes i must use Portable40 version, thanks