# Serialize to JSON Linq select result "WhereSelectArrayIterator"

Tags: c#, json, linq

I need to serialise only some fields from Offices, only Name and ID

```
public IEnumerable<Office> Offices;

public string SerializedPointOffices
{
    get { return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Offices ); }
}
```

I have one Linq select

```
 IEnumerable<MyObj>  offices = GetAllOffices();
 var test = offices.Select(t => new { t.OfficeName, t.OfficeID});
```

How Serialize this `test`?

type of test is `WhereSelectArrayIterator`

Comment: Need some more description.

Comment: What type of serialization are you looking for? XML, JSON, Binary?...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I serialize a C# anonymous type to a JSON string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/331976/how-do-i-serialize-a-c-sharp-anonymous-type-to-a-json-string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not entirely sure of your question, however, assuming you want to serialize an array or list of anonymous types to JSON, its pretty simple.

as above:

```
var test = offices.Select(t => new { t.OfficeName, t.OfficeID});
string str = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(test);
```

You can also use the Data Contract serialize annotations on your office object so that only the fields you want get serialized when you serialize the object. Personally, I prefer that way because I don't like sending anonymous types over the wire, I like having a strongly defined interface.