# Create complex JSON string

Tags: c#, json

I'm trying to create this JSON string in C#

```
[
  {
    accountId = 123,
    reportType = 1,
    reportTypeDesc = "Daily"
  },
  {
    accountId = 123,
    reportType = 1,
    reportTypeDesc = "Daily"
  },
  {
    accountId = 123,
    reportType = 1,
    reportTypeDesc = "Daily"
  }
]
```

I tried this way to do this json  , here is my code :

```
    var body = new []

            new
            {
                accountId = 123,
                reportType = 1,
                reportTypeDesc = "Daily"
            },
               new
            {
                accountId = 123,
                reportType = 1,
                reportTypeDesc = "Daily"
            },
               new
            {
               accountId = 123,
               reportType = 1,
               reportTypeDesc = "Daily"
            },
```

But I have compiler errors in "new[]" area

What is the right way to make this Json ? i tried all lots of different variation but nothing works

Comment: You forgot the braces: `new[] { ... }`

Comment: I have been happy using this framework for my json serialization needs: http://www.newtonsoft.com/json If you're using visual studio, you can add it to your solution using nuget.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/331976/how-do-i-serialize-a-c-sharp-anonymous-type-to-a-json-string might help as well.

Comment: Step 1. Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json Step 2. JsonConvert.SerializeObject<Sample>(sample);

Comment: don't forget to mark answer as correct

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [newtonsoft Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) for this, see how:

```
var body = new object []{
  new
  {
    accountId = 123,
    reportType = 1,
    reportTypeDesc = "Daily"
  },
 new
  {
      accountId = 123,
      reportType = 1,
      reportTypeDesc = "Daily"
  },
 new
  {
     accountId = 123,
     reportType = 1,
     reportTypeDesc = "Daily"
    },
};
var jsonBody = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(body);
```

See it working in [my .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/gT1AZx).

Answer (score 0):

The best way to work around with `Json` in `c#` or `VB.Net` is to have a great library like, `Newtonsoft.Json`. This will make your whole work lots easier and quicker. So, just download that library and try coding.

**Remedy**

```
public class MainClass
{
    public class Items
    {
        public int accountId, reportType;
        public string reportTypeDesc;
        public Items()
        {

        }
        public Items(int accountId, int reportType, string reportTypeDesc)
        {
            this.accountId = accountId;
            this.reportType = reportType;
            this.reportTypeDesc = reportTypeDesc;
        }
    }
    public List<Items> allItems = new List<Items>();
    public string toJson() =>
        JsonConvert.SerializeObject(allItems);
}
```

**Execution**

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MainClass m = new MainClass();
        m.allItems.Add(new MainClass.Items(123, 1, "Daily"));
        m.allItems.Add(new MainClass.Items(123, 1, "Daily"));
        m.allItems.Add(new MainClass.Items(123, 1, "Daily"));
        string json = m.toJson();
        richTextBox1.AppendText(json);
    }
```