# ASP.NET MVC get specific columns from table in EF

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a table with below columns.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_QuizQue](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [question] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [opt1] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [opt2] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [opt3] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [ans] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL
    )
```

I am trying to get a random record from this table, but only specific columns Like id, question, opt1, opt2, opt3. Present I am getting random record but it is fetching all columns. I tried below code for fetching a record with specific columns

```
dbUserEntities obj = new dbUserEntities();
    // GET api/values
    public IEnumerable<tbl_QuizQue> Get()
    {
        var result = obj.tbl_QuizQue.OrderBy(r => Guid.NewGuid()).Select(o => new { o.id, o.question, o.opt1, o.opt2, o.opt3 });
        return result;
        }
```

Here, i am getting below error while `return result;`

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<AnonymousType#1>' to 
        'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<studentQuiz.tbl_QuizQue>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

Help me where I am doing wrong.

Comment: It'd be simpler just to fetch the entire entity. Your columns don't look like one of them is huge enough to justify the extra complexity.

Comment: The value of `result` is a collecton of anonymous object (created using `.Select()`), not a collction of `tbl_QuizQue` object, hence the exception.

Answer (score 2):

I'd do this:

```
public IEnumerable<tbl_QuizQue> Get()
{
    var result = obj.tbl_QuizQue.OrderBy(r => Guid.NewGuid())
        .Select(o => new { o.id, o.question, o.opt1, o.opt2, o.opt3 })
        .AsEnumerable()
        .Select(q => new tblQuizQue {q.id, q.question, q.opt1, q.opt2, q.opt3);
    return result;
}
```

By first getting back just the columns you are interested in, you can constrain the query. You can then map them into the object you are interested in.

Comment: Thanks for reply. But getting this error  **Cannot initialize type 'studentQuiz.tbl_QuizQue' with a collection initializer because it does not implement 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'**

Comment: What does tbl_QuizQue look like?

Comment: You can see CREATE script in the question for tbl_QuizQue .

Comment: That's the table. What about the c# class declaration? That's what is behind the error you mentioned. I suspect your return type  of IEnumerable<tbl_QuiteQue> is incorrect.

Comment: C# code :  **public IEnumerable<tbl_QuizQue> Get()
        {
             var result = obj.tbl_QuizQue.OrderBy(r => Guid.NewGuid())
                        .Select(o => new { o.id, o.question, o.opt1, o.opt2, o.opt3 })
                        .AsEnumerable()
                        .Select(q => new tbl_QuizQue {q.id, q.question, q.opt1, q.opt2, q.opt3});
            return result;
        }**

Answer (score 0):

Change the return type of the Get function to

```
IEnumerable<dynamic>
```

and your code will execute.

As for whether it's a good idea, I guess you have to defer to the customs of the c# tribe.

I'd be tempted to use it all the time.

Comment: It is working in REST Client where I am getting the record with specific columns. But, in Chrome I am getting error.  **Type '<>f__AnonymousType3`5[System.Int32,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String]' cannot be serialized. Consider marking it with the DataContractAttribute attribute, and marking all of its members you want serialized with the DataMemberAttribute attribute. If the type is a collection, consider marking it with the CollectionDataContractAttribute. See the Microsoft .NET Framework documentation for other supported types.**

Comment: I don't think using `dynamic` here is very good architecture. Dynamic is a big can of worms to open just like that, you lose type safety for one.

Comment: That's another question. I'm surprised it works in the rest client and fails in the browser. Perhaps you aren't setting the right content type. Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/331976/how-do-i-serialize-a-c-sharp-anonymous-type-to-a-json-string

Comment: In the browser, I am getting results in XML format and JSON in REST Client.

Comment: So that's your new question. How do you serialize a dynamic object as XML.

Comment: Using dynamic is just a hack to get this working, you shouldn't do that unless you have a good reason.